# Remove ?view=featured from joomla 3 URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have several websites running Joomla 3 and I can't seem to figure out how to stop Joomla from generating a duplicate of the homepage with this URL: www.domain.com/?view=featured

Ideally I'd like to be able to disable this page from being created, but a htaccess redirect should also be sufficient. I have not had any luck getting a redirect to work either though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: This theoretically should work, however it does not.

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=featured$
    RewriteRule ^component/content/$ http://www.yoursite.com/? [L,R=301]

Comment: which component ? joomla default component or custom component ?.. problem is in `router` file

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule as your **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?view=featured [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```